How to use JWT to obtain the info of the currently logged in user?
I'm working on a web app using vuejs and ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to sign in a custom identity user and send back a token back to the client to user to get all the info of the current logged in user, but when I send the request to fetch the info, I'm always unauthorized.
Here is the program.cs, the custom identity user and the controller for the custom identity user and the client side to send the request to fetch the info:
using JobHosting.Models;
using JobHosting.Models.Repositories;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

// Jwt Configuration
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = config["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = config["JwtSettings:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["JwtSettings:Key"]) ),
            ValidateIssuer = true, 
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobListingRepository, JobListingRepository>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserAccount, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            });
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace JobHosting.Models
{
    public class UserAccount : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string UserType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string JHFullName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string JHResume { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public String JListerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public String JListerWebsite { get; set; } = string.Empty ;
        public List<int> Listings { get; set; } = new List<int>();

        public UserAccount(string Email, string UserName, string UserType)
        {
            this.Email = Email;
            this.UserName = UserName;
            this.UserType = UserType;
        }
    
        override public String ToString()
        {
            return Id + " " + UserName + " " + UserType + " " + Email + " ";
        }
    }
}

using JobHosting.Models;
using JobHosting.Models.Repositories;
using JobHosting.Models.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace JobHosting.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Authentication")]
    [ApiController]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class UserAccountsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<UserAccount> jobHuntingUM;
        private readonly SignInManager<UserAccount> jobHuntingSM;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public UserAccountsController(UserManager<UserAccount> jobHuntingUM, SignInManager<UserAccount> jobHuntingSM, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.jobHuntingSM = jobHuntingSM;
            this.jobHuntingUM = jobHuntingUM;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost("SignUp")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserAccount>> SignUp([FromBody]SignUpViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (await jobHuntingUM.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email) == null) 
                    {
                        UserAccount user = new (model.Email, model.UserName, model.UserType);
                        Console.WriteLine(user.Email+" "+user.UserName+" "+user.UserType+" "+model.Password+" "+user.Password);
                        var res = await jobHuntingUM.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                        if (res.Succeeded)
                        {
                            await jobHuntingSM.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, "SignUp successful, you have been signed in");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var errors = "";

                            foreach(var error in res.Errors)
                            {
                                errors += error.Description;
                            }

                            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, errors);// $"An error has occurred while creating the new user {errors}");
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, "User with that email already exists");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "invalid input data");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("SignOut")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserAccount>> Logout()
        {
            await jobHuntingSM.SignOutAsync();
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost("SignIn")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserAccount>> SignIn([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            try 
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var user = await jobHuntingUM.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

                    if (user == null || !await jobHuntingUM.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Wrong username or password");
                    }

                    var res = await jobHuntingSM.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

                    if (res.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                            };

                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:key"]));
                        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                                                         audience: configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                                                         claims: claims,
                                                         expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                         signingCredentials: creds);

                        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

                        return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return Unauthorized("invalid login attempt");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                return BadRequest($"error {e.Message}");
            }

            return null;
        }

        [HttpGet("Info")]
        //[Authorize]
        public ActionResult<UserAccount> GetCurrentUser()
        {
            try
            {
                var email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
                var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);

                foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Claim Type: {claim.Type}, Claim Value: {claim.Value}");
                }

                if (email == null || userName == null) 
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }

                return Ok(new { Email = email, UserName = userName });
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}


<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
export default {
    name: "UserSettingsView",
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute()
        const token = route.params.token;
        const userData = ref({})
        onMounted(() => {
            console.log(token)
            axios.get("https://localhost:7075/api/Authentication/Info",
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(response => userData.value = response.data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
        return {
            token,
            userData
        }
    }
}
</script>
<template>
<!--This is a placeholder for what is to come-->
{{ userData }}
<h1>User info</h1>
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" v-model="userData.email" placeholder="name example">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">IsEmailConfirmed</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userData.isEmailConfirmed" placeholder="Expiration date">
    </div>
</form>
</template>

I tried sending the bearer token in the header of the request and that didn't work and honestly that's about as deep as my understanding of how that should work goes.


I'm trying to sign in a custom identity user and send back a token
back to the client to user to get all the info of the current logged
in user, but when I send the request to fetch the info, I'm always
unauthorize.

Based on your shared code, description and scenario, I have tried to troubleshoot your scenario and code and I was able to reproduce your 401 error and also able to get the token and with the token succeeded to retrieve the userinfo.
Accoring to my test, I have seen your token generation code in controller and program.cs file seem correct.
However, I am not sure if you are calling the right endpoint for getting userinfo. Becuase, I haven't seen any endpoint with this URL /api/Authentication/Info.
Apart from that, you haven't explained if you were getting the token and wether the token has been passed into the request header accordingly. So this part is very crucial. I would recommend you to check those fact.
I have treid in following way:
Step: 1: First of all I have tried to call the GetUserInfo() endpoint which is https://localhost:7246/api/userinfo without the token at the begining to ensure, if endpoint could trace that. As you can see below:

Step:2: Secondly, I have generated the token using your existing code and I was able to get the token. Here is the reference for you.



Step:3: After getting the token I have sent the request to the userInfo endpoint and pass the token accordingly with the request header and access the user info. I have also checked if the request header has the token bind with it. Here is the reference:





I tried sending the bearer token in the header of the request and that
didn't work and honestly that's about as deep as my understanding of
how that should work goes.

First double check, if you are getting the token accordingly, Check your token if it has the correct user permission.
Once you confirm above stuff. Now check your vue.js endpoint if you are getting the token and it has bound with the request header properly.
Most importantly, add logging to your GetCurrentUser method to see if the token is being received and if claims are being read correctly.
I don't have vue.js environment. But you could refer to the Javascript fetch reqeust steps, below:
<h1>JWT Token Test</h1>
<button onclick="getToken()">Get Token</button>
<button onclick="getUserInfo()">Get User Info</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>

<script>
    let token = '';

    async function getToken() {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7246/api/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: 'testuser', password: 'testpassword' })
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        token = data.token;
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Token: ' + token;
    }

    async function getUserInfo() {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7246/api/userinfo', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'User Info: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Error: ' + response.statusText;
        }
    }
</script>

My token generation controller code same as yours and userInfo endpoint also same. Although, I am checking the token in request header to ensure if that's correct. So, I am adding those code if that needed for anyone else for future reference.
Demo appsettings.json:
"JwtSettings": {
  "Issuer": "KironAPITest",
  "Audience": "Test-audience",
  "Key": "ThisIsASecretKeyWithAtLeast32Characters!"
}

Request Mode:
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

Token Controller Action:
Route("api/token")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public TokenController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GenerateToken([FromBody] LoginModel login)
    {
        if (login.Username == "testuser" && login.Password == "testpassword")
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, login.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return Ok(new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) });
        }


        return Unauthorized();
    }
}

User Info Endpoint:
[Route("api/userinfo")]
[ApiController]
public class UserInfoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetUserInfo()
    {
        var headers = Request.Headers;
        var authHeader = headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        var token = authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? authHeader.Substring(7) : authHeader;
        var username = "Kiron from authenticated endpoint";
        return Ok(new { Username = username });
    }
}

Note: Please refer to this official document for additional references.

Hey there ,thanks for your reply and sorry for not providing all the details as this is my first post. To clarify, i have verified that the api route is correct and that the claim is successfully made with all the info being as expected once i logged it to console. Furthermore, the token which the SignIn method generates does pass successfully to the GetUserInfo method but the issue is there are no claims in there. Thank you again for your help.

I have also forgot to mention that i've tested the token on jwt.io and it seemed to work as intended except for the fact that it always says "invalid signature"

If you get no claims for that user, then first double check the the credentials are correct, then check the whether you are getting the user details or if the user exist then need to move further steps. You need to debug it. First check the sample I made for you to ensure if you are getting the user claims. So that you would understand where's the issue.

i tried checking the credentials and it seems that's where the issue lies i think, it seems that the token does that include the signingCredentials upon creation. Here's a token on jwt.io as an example the payload and header are fine but the signature is invalid it was generated using your code :
https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwianRpIjoiOTA4ZDg5ZjQtZDIyOS00NzEzLWJmN2UtOTE1MzgxMWY2ZjBiIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIxMTIzNjA1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwNzUvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwLyJ9.rEk_9uN2VBJ2KQLK4PFpmlX8a-DbdlPdsShQr2b49AI

Double check the code and configuration, I have used this config ""JwtSettings": {   "Issuer": "KironAPITest",   "Audience": "Test-audience",   "Key": "ThisIsASecretKeyWithAtLeast32Characters!" }" and its working as expected not sure why you are getting signingCredentials  issue

"JwtSettings": {
"Key": "YourSuperSecureKeyThatHasAtLeast32Bytes!",
"Issuer": "http://localhost:7075/",
"Audience": "http://localhost:8080/"
}
that's my configuration, as for the code i'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with it. Maybe my configuration is incorrect?

First of all, try the flat one I gave you, make sure you have able to make it work, then try to implement your changes step by step, so that you could narrow down the issue. Other than, it would hard to get the reason why yours one not working.

alright i'll try doing that, thank you for your time.

Sure, I hope you would be able to make it work, if still doesn't work, feel free to let me know, I will try to assist you.
